# Java! have to count symbols in a file

Tags: java, file, count

I did the code but am getting 0 as a result. Can you help me with this issue? Thanks in advance

NOTE: White-blank or space shouldn't be considered as a symbol.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



public class KerkoSimbolet{

    private File fileIn;    

    public KerkoSimbolet(File fileIn){
        this.fileIn = fileIn;
    }

    public void countSymbols()throws IOException{
        int count = 0;
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileIn);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("donati");

        try{
            while(reader.read()!= -1){
                //if(!reader.equals(" "))
                    count++;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            reader.close();
        }
        try{
            fw.write(count);
            fw.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            fw.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []arg){

        File fi = new File("ubt.txt");
        KerkoSimbolet ks = new KerkoSimbolet(fi);
        try{
            ks.countSymbols();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes I use albanian language since the homework is from there.

Heres the new code I came up with that counts spaces

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KerkoSimbolet{

private File fileIn;

public KerkoSimbolet(File fileIn){
    this.fileIn = fileIn;
}

public void countSymbols()throws IOException{
    int count = 0;
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileIn);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("donati");

    try{
        while(reader.read()!= -1){
            if(!reader.equals(""))
                count++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        reader.close();
    }
    try{
        fw.write(Integer.toString(count));
        fw.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        fw.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String []arg){

    File fi = new File("ubt.txt");
    KerkoSimbolet ks = new KerkoSimbolet(fi);
    try{
        ks.countSymbols();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `ubt.txt` has content right?

Comment: What is the assignment? What result do you expect?

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: @karthik yes it has something in it

Comment: @RealSkeptic assignment is to create a code that has a method to count the number of characters on a file excluding white spaces

Comment: @XOR no, I'm just a beginner don't know anything about debugging and I'm using notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies how you write your count, rather than the counting itself. According to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html), `FileWriter#write(int)`:

> Writes a single character.

This is not what you want (I would guess). The correct implementation would be

```
public void countSymbols() throws IOException{
    int count = 0;
    try(FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileIn)) {
        int cread;
        while((cread = reader.read()) != -1){
            //if(!reader.equals(" "))
                count++;
        }
    }
    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("donati")) {
        fw.write(Integer.toString(count));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yee the mistake was at the method write(), fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
   while(reader.read()!= -1){
            //if(!reader.equals(" ")) // I think you wanted to use reader.read() here 
                count++;
        }
```

is also wrong once you read a character you have to store it in a variable and then check whether it's `space` or not

Do the following:

```
        int input;
        try{
             while((input = reader.read())!= -1){
                if(input!=32) // 32 is the ascii value of space
                   count++;
              }
            }
```

Comment: i just noticed that with both my code and your it still counts white spaces, any other suggestion??

Comment: @DonatKajtazi Did you try this code properly? because this does not count spaces. As we are checking `if(input!=32)` it will skip space, because Ascii value of space is 32.

Comment: can you post your code as it is in the question? Don't remove current code but just add it separately.

Comment: here you go i posted it

Comment: @DonatKajtazi your while loop is still wrong, compare it with my for loop. you are writing `while(reader.read()!= -1){` which is incorrect, read my answer again.